# HightCharts: How to align pie chart positions to right or left corner of the container

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts

How can I align the pie chart in the highcharts to the right end or left end in the container? i have notice that center:[] property works using percentage but getting some position issues while resizing the container. Please check the below fiddle link.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-legend/)

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    plotBackgroundColor: null,
    plotBorderWidth: null,
    plotShadow: false,
    type: 'pie'
},
title: {
    text: 'Browser market shares in January, 2018'
},
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
},
plotOptions: {
    pie: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
        },
        showInLegend: true
    }
},
series: [..]
```

});

Comment: Try removing the "max-width" CSS property for the "container" div.

Comment: No Vinay its not working with 100% width :(

Comment: Change your container html code as below. It worked in fiddle at least.
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px;float:left;"></div>

Comment: As my outer container is resizable, cant fixed the min-width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **style** property for the chart. Please look at the attached example:

```
chart: {
    plotBackgroundColor: null,
    width: 200,
    height: 300,
    type: 'pie',
    style: {
        'float': 'right'
    }
},
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2at3g47f/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.style

Comment: this works with specific width and height but how to align with (width:100%, height:100%)

Comment: Hi fekky Dev, Maybe translate the SVG series group element will do the job? Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ux2k4vsw/

Comment: great, this works but if I enable data labels seems some alignment issues

Comment: Hi Fatma elzahraa , In this case, you need to also translate dataLabels group: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fso4jdta/